# ¿Evitar cerrar navegador sin antes haber presionado un botón de cerrar sesión?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una web en la cual los usuarios ingresan y deseo evitar que cierren el navegador sin antes haber presionado el botón de cerrar sesión que he puesto. La razón de esto es que necesito obligar que hagan esta acción para poder cambiar un estado de activo a inactivo al salir que guardo en la db.

Comment: lo que te puedo sugerir es que utilices algo adicional como electron, sucede que los navegadores no se pueden manipular desde la pagina con javascript, ni con otro lenguaje, esto no seria coerente, puedes lanzar algun script que te cierre la sesion al momento de detectar que se cierra la pestaña, pero no puedes evitar que se cierre, simplemente mostrar un mensaje de advertencia si es que desean abandonar la pagina

Comment: @jeanpitx `...los navegadores no se pueden manipular desde la pagina con Javascript...` hhmm... para eso se inventó JavaScript y de hecho Electron es básicamente un motor de JavaScript sin ser navegador siendo el mismo caso, no puedes evitar que el usuario cierre el proceso de Electron, al igual que el navegador.

Comment: @Azteca puedes manipular el contenido dentro del navegador, mas no el navegador como tal, a que me refiero, que no podras cambiar el color del navegador, la barra de menus, y otras opciones que solo el usuario las puede hacer al manipular el navegador. El navegador es un interprete de html y javascript.

Comment: @jeanpitx Es correcto, y no solo eso, también soporta muchísimos otros protocolos como FTP, FILE, etc, pero a lo que voy es que no creo que recomendar que comience de nuevo su proyecto con Electron cuando la solución que pide está en JavaScript. Vaya, vamos a responder la pregunta y en caso de que no sea pueda, lo mas cercano.

Comment: Creo que se debe definir una estrategia de "timeout", a la que se ligue un timer en la página de modo que cada n/minutos haga ping automático  mediante ajax al servidor, en caso de que no lo haga la sesión se cierra, eso obvia problemas de cierres abruptos y, el estado puede registrarse mediante un cron del lado del servidor que monitorée que conexiones no enviaron su ping en un lapso de tiempo prudente.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes evitar que cierren el navegador o la conexión por obvias razones, lo que puedes hacer es escuchar el evento de "cerrar" la ventana/tab y disparar el mismo evento que como si hiciera clic en el botón de "cerrar sesión" con jQuery:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    cerrarSesion();
});
```

o Directo del DOM con Javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    cerrarSesion();
};
```

Comment: No he probado mecanismos como ese. Pero, y si hay un corte de energía? o si se cae la conn con el proveedor de acceso web?, etc. Si se reinicia el equipo sin haber cerrado el navegador? etc. Nunca habrá mensaje al servidor. La solución debe ser de otro estilo. Es más, no tengo certeza de que al cerrar un navegador con n pestañas abiertas, y configurado para reabrirse como estaba, notifique a las páginas, en pestañas inactivas, que está siendo cerrado.

Comment: En ese caso la solución sencilla está de el otro lado de la conexión, en el lado del servidor de la pagina web, en el httpd ya sea Nginx, Apache, etc.
Espera a el "timeout" de cada conexión y registrar el "inactivo" en la db.

Comment: Si, pero permitiendo que las conexiones envíen señales de estar activas, sin que el usuario tenga que estar pinchando páginas o haciendo llamados. Es usual que uno no esté amarrado a una página y se distraiga momentáneamente en otras por algunos minutos

Comment: @quevedo No existe solucuón cuando existe un corte de energía, aparte este método que trata de emplear no tiene sentido a todo los usuarios no le puede pasar lo mismo, la mejor solución es que si no detecta actividad en el sitio este muestre una ventana diciendo que se va a cerrar  en `x` segundos por su inactividad y si el usurario se da cuenta de aquel mensaje darle la opción de dos botones de `continuar en la web` o `Si, cerrar sesión`

Answer (score 1):

No puedes dejar el control de los usuarios en manos del cliente, por lo que la solución no puede pasar exclusivamente por javascript. Una solución basada plenamente en JS puede ser burlada de forma sencilla.

Por ejemplo, si se hace uso del evento window.onbeforeunload, es posible eliminar con código inyectado en la consola cualquier relación entre el evento y el manejador. También es posible terminar el proceso del navegador de forzosamente. En cualquiera de los casos la solución no funcionará. El servidor debe tomar parte en la solución del problema.

Como ha indicado Quevedo, una estrategia de timeout debería ser la adecuada. Si has establecido un token de autenticación y la transacción de los datos se realiza mediante una conexión cifrada (como HTTPS), entonces tu problema se resuelve de la siguiente forma.

1. Tus clientes envían una petición al servidor para que su sesión no caduque cada diez minutos (por ejemplo).
2. Las peticiones son manejadas por el servidor, que comprueba la autenticidad del token y guarda la fecha actual del servidor como fecha en la que ha recibido la solicitud.
3. Por otro lado, cada doce minutos (por ejemplo, debe ser un periodo ligeramente más elevado que el anterior) una rutina se lanza en el servidor que comprueba la información de las solicitudes de mantener la sesión activa. Toda sesión activa que no haya recibido solicitud en los últimos doce minutos (el mismo tiempo que antes) es considerada cerrada.

**¿Por qué doce minutos y no diez en el ejemplo?**

Porque las peticiones no son instantáneas. Suponer lo siguiente:

Suponer que la rutina se lanza en el servidor cada diez minutos.
Suponer un tiempo 0, será el inicio del servidor.

A tiempo 0 el servidor realiza su comprobación, no hay nadie conectado.

Tras diez minutos, ocurre lo siguiente:

- El servidor vuelve a realizar la rutina.
- Un usuario inicia sesión. Esta sesión queda registrada en el sistema

Tras otros diez minutos:

- El navegador del usuario realiza la petición. La petición tarda un segundo en llegar al servidor.
- El servidor vuelve a a realizar la rutina, pero no encuentra registro alguno del usuario que se conectó (la petición no llegará hasta pasado un segundo) así que da de baja al usuario.

Como se puede observar, si los tiempos son iguales es posible dar de baja a un usuario que no se ha dado de baja.

Consideraciones:

**Es posible que el usuario otorgue voluntariamente el token de autenticación a un tercero que envíe las peticiones por él.**

Sí, es cierto, pero si esto ocurriera, el usuario estaría técnicamente conectado, ya que la identidad del usuario está en el token.

Answer (score -1):

Debes jugar con la condición en el evento beforeUnload.

Por ejemplo si tienes "tuVariableDeSession" y le asignas el valor "open" o "close", puedes hacer algo como esto.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
        e = e || window.event;

        if (tuVariableDeSession == "open") {
            if (e) {
                e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
            }
            // Esta es para Safari
            return 'Sure?';
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Estás seguro de que todos los eventuales cierres del navegador dispararán el evento en todas las pestañas cargadas, activas o no?